# Tqdm for a progress bar per process pool worker

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

The task I am trying to achieve is to process thousands of artifacts of different sizes on a multi core machine. I wish to use the process pool executor to distribute the jobs and have each worker tell me which file it is working on.

So far, I have the following:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

from itertools import islice, cycle

import time
import tqdm
import multiprocessing
import random

worker_count = min(multiprocessing.cpu_count(), 10)
flist=range(100)
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=worker_count)

with tqdm.tqdm(total=len(flist), leave=False) as t:
    t.set_description_str("Extracting ... ")
    pbars = []

    for idx in range(t.pos + 1, t.pos + 1 + worker_count):
        pbars.append(tqdm.tqdm(position=idx, bar_format='{desc}', leave=False))

    def process(entry):
        artifact, idx = entry
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, worker_count)/10.0)
        pbars[idx].set_description_str(f'Working on {artifact}', refresh=True)
        return artifact
    for _, _ in zip(flist, executor.map(process, zip(flist, islice(cycle(range(worker_count)), len(flist))))):
        t.update()

    for idx in range(worker_count):
        pbars[idx].set_description_str(" "*(pbars[idx].ncols - 1), refresh=True)
        pbars[idx].clear()
        pbars[idx].close()
```

[image: Running demo]

Of course, instead of the numbers, I will be displaying the file names.

Now, the questions are:

1. Is there a better pythonic way to achieve what I want?
2. The last bit about clearing pbars seems obnoxious to me. I do that basically to clear up the terminal when the program finishes. Perhaps there is a better way?